# How write GLUT keyboard functions?

Tags: c, opengl, keyboard-events

I wrote the code below, but at runtime, when I press keys, the program doesn't work.
I want to write a program that draws a triangle when the user presses `right_key` and `alt_key`. But this doesn't work at all. It always shows a black screen.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
void init (void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,200.0);
}
float red=1,green=1,blue=1;
void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {
    if(key=='0')
        exit(0);
    int mod;
    if(key== GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {
        mod = glutGetModifiers();
        if (mod==GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT) {
            red = 1.0; green = 0.0; blue = 0.0;
            glColor3f(red,green,blue);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(0,100);
            glVertex2f(50,100);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,20);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutCreateWindow("A simple example");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: OpenGL doesn't do any keayboard handling. What you probably mean is GLUT, which doesn't have anything to do with OpenGL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK it works now. I've modified your code to enable ALT or  SHIFT or  CTRL. The code prints out the scancodes of the keys.
To print the ALT, CTRL OR SHIFT scancode, simply press ALT or  SHIFT or  CTRL in combination with other keys.
Otherwse GLUT won't register it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float red=1,green=1,blue=1;



void init (void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,200.0);
}


void process_SHIFT_ALT_CTRL(unsigned char key, int x, int y) 
{
    // Press ALT or  SHIFT or  CTRL in combination with other keys.
    printf("key_code =%d  \n",key);

    int mod = glutGetModifiers();

    if (mod != 0) //ALT=4  SHIFT=1  CTRL=2
    {      
          switch(mod)
          {
             case 1 :  printf("SHIFT key %d\n",mod);  break;
             case 2 :  printf("CTRL  key %d\n",mod);  break;
             case 4 :  printf("ALT   key %d\n",mod);  break;
             mod=0;
          }
    }
}


void process_Normal_Keys(int key, int x, int y) 
{
     switch (key) 
    {    
       case 27 :      break;
       case 100 : printf("GLUT_KEY_LEFT %d\n",key);   break;
       case 102: printf("GLUT_KEY_RIGHT %d\n",key);  ;  break;
       case 101   : printf("GLUT_KEY_UP %d\n",key);  ;  break;
       case 103 : printf("GLUT_KEY_DOWN %d\n",key);  ;  break;
    }

}


void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("Press ALT or  SHIFT or  CTRL in combination with other keys. \n\n");

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(800,20);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutCreateWindow("A simple example");
    init();

    // famous GLUT callback functions

    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    glutSpecialFunc( process_Normal_Keys );
    glutKeyboardFunc( process_SHIFT_ALT_CTRL );  


    glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `glutSpecialFunc( process_Normal_Keys );`, really?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work that way, because the calls to your keyboard callback will be run asynchronously.

That means, you won't see a triangle drawn, unless the keystroke happens to be processed right between `glClear()` and `glFlush()`, which will happen rather seldomly and only for one single frame.

What you have to do is rather straightforward:
Upon processing the keystroke, save that status, e.g. set a boolean variable to true/false depending on the key input.

Then check for that in `display()` and draw the triangle, if requested.

Pseudo code example:

```
bool status = false;

inputhandler(key)
{
    if(key == KEY_A)
        status = true
    else if(KEY == KEY_S)
        status = false;
}

displayhandler()
{
    clear();
    if(status)
        drawTriangle();
    flush();
}

main()
{
    //... init etc.
    glutDisplayFunc(&displayhandler);
    glutSpecialFunc(&inputhandler);
}
```

On further notes, if you'd like to get into OpenGL programming without having to worry about handling other stuff around that, I'd recommend using a premade library handling windows, inputs, etc. for you, e.g. [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). They work similar to glut, but they're in general more powerful and will still allow you to run OpenGL calls directly, while offering simplified event handling.

Comment: can I call   glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys) func. in display function?

Comment: The keyboard callback won't *ever* run *while* the display callback is running. If it were so, one would need to synchronize access to shared state.

Comment: `glutSpecialFunc()` isn't actually calling the keyboard processing. It just defines the callback function to be called, essentially tells glut "if there's keyboard input any time, call x". I'll add a short simplified example to what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate graphics commands in the keyboard callback. Set some piece of global state when the key you're interested is pressed and use the information in the display code.

The way to debug problems like this is to use printf statements in the code you think isn't working. Here adding a printf in the keyboard handler would soon tell you that the code is being executed but the triangle not being drawn. That might have lead you to think about when a graphics command is possible and when it isn't.